# checkbox values are not getting displayed

Tags: php

I am trying to export selected names to excel. But before exporting , when i select the values  through checkbox, its not getting selected.

I am doing like this

```
<form action="select.php" method="post" >
{listing_dataset}
<div class="listing result_row_{row_num_even_odd}">
    <div class="listingtitle">

    **<input type="checkbox" name="name" />**
        <a href="{edit_listing_link}" title="{lang_admin_listings_editor_modify_listing}">{listing_title}</a> <span class="listingid">({listingid})</span>
```

and closing form at the end like this

```
<input type="submit" value="EXPORT SELECTED" name="export" />
</form>
```

in select.php, i am trying to get the selected name which is not happening, instead it just displays **'on'**

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['export']))

{
$name = $_POST['name'];

echo $name; 
}

?>
```

what i should do to get the values? please suggest

Comment: Do a `print_r($_POST);` and you will get to know how that value is being passed

Comment: Where is value in your checkbox?

Comment: @shadow: I gave value as `value="{listing_title}"`, now i get the single value when i print it. if i select multple checkboxes it is not displaying :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give the value attribute to your `checkbox`

```
<input type="checkbox" name="name" value="something" />
```

may be `{listingid}` or `{listing_title}` in your case

Comment: thanks for the answer. But it is not displaying all the selected values instead it selects only one value :(

Comment: Can you please guide me in this zzlalani

Comment: Thanks to all. I found the solution for it!

Answer (score 0):

For every checkbox, you have to provide value as directed by zzlalani. If the checkboxes are in the same group, just provide the same name to each.

The name of every checkbox item should be same. The values has to be different(in your case).